# Unspecified error when initializing AZSCloudStorageAccount in azure-storage-ios SDK

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Xcode 8.2.1

When running sample app (and before, when running my own app via Cocoapods) I get this error when initializing AZSCloudStorageAccount: 
`Error Domain=com.Microsoft.AzureStorage.ErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"`

from the line `try! storageAccount = AZSCloudStorageAccount(fromConnectionString: connectionString)` in BlobListTableViewController.swift

Any advice on how to debug to nail down the error further would be great!

Comment: It seems that you were running the sample code from https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios/blob/master/BlobSample/BlobSample/BlobListTableViewController.swift. The issue may be caused by using incorrect connection string. Please check the connection string whether you had copied correctly from azure portal.

Comment: Yup, definitely using my AZS connection string copied directly from the portal. Thanks for the thought though!

Answer (score 0):

According to the content of [`README.md`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios/blob/9b7a89f4935e92dd5d02d3a0d74106a522ad7746/BlobSample/README.txt) file for BlobSample of azure storage for ios, the issue might be caused by not compatible with your current Xcode version 8.2.1, please see below.

> README - READ THIS BEFORE ATTEMPTING TO RUN THE SAMPLE APP
>
> This sample is written in SWIFT, targeting iOS 9.0 and **using XCode 7**.  **If you have a different setup, the sample may not run
> properly.**  More samples (for Objective-C, and tested against older versions of iOS are coming soon.)

So for resolving this issue, I suggest that you need to downgrade the Xcode version, or using [Azure Storage REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/azure-storage-services-rest-api-reference) in swift instead of SDK.

Hope it helps.